# Can't find `fun Cursor.getString(columnName: String): String` implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-ktx

Where to these functions implemented?

> https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.database/android.database.-cursor/index.html

I saw package androidx.core.database but can't find implementation.
There are only the functions like these.

```
inline fun Cursor.getBlobOrNull(index: Int) = if (isNull(index)) null else getBlob(index)
inline fun Cursor.getDoubleOrNull(index: Int) = if (isNull(index)) null else getDouble(index)
inline fun Cursor.getFloatOrNull(index: Int) = if (isNull(index)) null else getFloat(index)
inline fun Cursor.getIntOrNull(index: Int) = if (isNull(index)) null else getInt(index)
inline fun Cursor.getLongOrNull(index: Int) = if (isNull(index)) null else getLong(index)
inline fun Cursor.getShortOrNull(index: Int) = if (isNull(index)) null else getShort(index)
inline fun Cursor.getStringOrNull(index: Int) = if (isNull(index)) null else getString(index)
```

Comment: have you changed the version or added the dependency on the build.gradle recently? Have you tried to run the `./gradlew clean` task before building it?

Comment: Yes, but can't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name-based extensions for `Cursor` have been removed by Jake Wharton.

In his words:

> They encourage a pattern of inefficiency. You should look up the
>   column names once prior to iteration or use a higher-level abstraction
>   like Room or SQL Delight which does that for you.

You can find the full git history for this package here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+log/android-room-release/core/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/core/database